# Which of these functions are linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem. 
[image]

A - I think is linear by definition
B - Now, I don't think this is linear, but I marked it anyway because I was unsure   (you're multiplying)
C - I am on the boundary with this too, but I think this IS linear. Never mind my marking   in the image.
D - This is linear
E - This too I think is linear by definition
F - This is obviously not linear because it is multiplying.

But, the program says I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For a function to be linear, you require that $F(c~\overrightarrow x) = cF(\overrightarrow x)$ for some real number $c$.

The determinant of an $n$ by $n$ matrix has the following property:

$$\det(cA) = c^n\det(A)$$

and the property that:

> If you multiply one row (or column) of matrix $A$ to get matrix $B$, then
>   $$c\det(A) = \det(B)$$

Or

$$c \det\begin{bmatrix} \overrightarrow x \\ \overrightarrow y \\ \overrightarrow z \end{bmatrix} = 
\det\begin{bmatrix} c\overrightarrow x \\ \overrightarrow y \\ \overrightarrow z \end{bmatrix} = 
\det\begin{bmatrix} \overrightarrow x \\ c\overrightarrow y \\ \overrightarrow z \end{bmatrix} = 
\det\begin{bmatrix} \overrightarrow x \\ \overrightarrow y \\ c\overrightarrow z \end{bmatrix}$$

$$c \det[ \overrightarrow x ~ \overrightarrow y ~ \overrightarrow z ] = 
\det[ c\overrightarrow x ~ \overrightarrow y ~ \overrightarrow z ] = 
\det[ \overrightarrow x ~ c\overrightarrow y ~ \overrightarrow z ] =  
\det[ \overrightarrow x ~ \overrightarrow y ~ c\overrightarrow z ] $$

Now you can see, for example, that **A** does not give a linear function:

$$\begin{align}
F(c A) &= \det\left((cA)^T(cA)\right) \\
& = \det\left(c^2 A^TA\right)\\
& = \left(c^2\right)^n \det\left(A^TA\right) \\
& = c^{2n} F(A) \\
& \ne c F(A) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are off the mark in most cases.

A, D: The determinant is a polynomial function of degree $3$ in its $9$ entries, and is therefore not linear in these (resp. as a function of the matrix formed by thes entries). The identity matrix $I$ has $\det(I)=1$, but $\det(I+I)=8$.

B, E: The determinant is a three-linear function in its row-, or column vectors. When the variable vector $x$ appears in two rows, resp., columns then the resulting function $F(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ in the coordinates of $x$. In particular $F(2x)=4 F(x)$. So again $F(x)$ is not linear in $x$.

C, F: Here the variable vector $x$ appears as a single row, resp., column of the matrix in question. Therefore $F(x)$ is indeed linear.